# Simple Java 2D graphics: draw a rectangle?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get a Java 2D graphics "hello world" going, and am finding it strangely difficult (ie, I'm Googling variations of "java hello world example" and coming up empty).  Can anyone help me with a minimal hellow world example?

**Edit**

This is a good starting point though, ["The Java Tutorials: Performing Custom Painting"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: So, mm, with your rep. I know somethings going on, but could you still expand/refine the question?

Comment: I'm a noob with Java -- just trying to get set up quickly, and am really lost.

Comment: *"just trying to get set up quickly"*  ..by 'set up DYM 'down-votes'?  Here is a -1 for your collection.  Show some effort in future.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you sir, may I have another?

Comment: What is missing from your question is a clear indication of just what confuses you. You state that you find things "strangely difficult", but yet you don't clarify the difficulty for us. Yes, we can regurgitate code, but we can't help with specific help if you don't give specific information regarding your points of confusion. Quality in is equivalent to quality out.

Comment: *"may I have another?"* Link to another of your questions (or answers) of the same caliber as that (i.e. rubbish) and I'll be glad to oblige.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yea, I see your point.  I guess I was hoping for an *online sandbox* along the lines of JSFiddle / Ideone.  Does that really not exist for Java 2d graphics?  I have to download the JDK, compile the source at the command line, and load up the applet in a browser?  Oh, the humanity ...

Comment: @AndrewThompson if you'd pull your head out of your ass for a few minutes, you might see value in questions that don't fit your pre-conceived template.  Just a thought.

Comment: JSFiddle / Ideone are foreign concepts to me, so I can't help you from that angle. If your problem is an inability or unwillingness to download the resources necessary to compile and run Java, not many others can help you either. May the lord have mercy on your soul.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels may the lord have mercy on us all, my good sir.  May god have mercy on us all.  (Thx for your answer btw, it was helpful.)

Comment: and the congregation said, "amen".

Comment: `"So apparently the Java community, in its barbarism, ..."` -- about all I can say to this is "ungowa".

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Tongue-in-cheek - I fully acknowledge my ignorance.  I'm just surprised there's no online sandbox.  What if you're out somewhere, at a public computer, whatever, and you want to test some code?  There's no quick & dirty way to do it...

Comment: I honestly cannot say if an online sandbox does or does not exist, other than [what I can find on Google](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php), and these seem to have problems with GUI type programs. My ignorance is even worse in that I've not had the experience of using this sort of thing for Java or other programming languages.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To draw a rectangle in Swing you should:

- First of all, never draw directly in the JFrame or other top-level window.
- Instead draw in a JPanel, JComponent or other class that eventually extends from JComponent.
- You should override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.
- You should be sure to call the super method
- You should draw your rectangle with the Graphics object provided to the method by the JVM.
- You should read the painting in Swing tutorial.

Clear?

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawRect extends JPanel {
   private static final int RECT_X = 20;
   private static final int RECT_Y = RECT_X;
   private static final int RECT_WIDTH = 100;
   private static final int RECT_HEIGHT = RECT_WIDTH;

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      // draw the rectangle here
      g.drawRect(RECT_X, RECT_Y, RECT_WIDTH, RECT_HEIGHT);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      // so that our GUI is big enough
      return new Dimension(RECT_WIDTH + 2 * RECT_X, RECT_HEIGHT + 2 * RECT_Y);
   }

   // create the GUI explicitly on the Swing event thread
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      DrawRect mainPanel = new DrawRect();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawRect");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but I'm not sure you need invokeLater in the thread that constructs the frame, especially since it's not visible until the very end.

Comment: this is the MINIMUM needed to draw a single rectangle in Java??   0_o'

Comment: @johnktejik: To draw one with Swing, this works well. Note that recently Swing has been superseded by JavaFX.

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a class that extends from `JComponent` (or one of its subclasses, like `JPanel` in the below example) and overrides `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. Here's an example:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private int squareX = 50;
    private int squareY = 50;
    private int squareW = 20;
    private int squareH = 20;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // do your superclass's painting routine first, and then paint on top of it.
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(squareX,squareY,squareW,squareH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good example: 1+ up-vote (surprised?)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Not at all. I decided to add an answer when I saw yours lacked an example. When you edited your answer to include an example, I up voted yours (although I prefer my example - yours has a lot of extra content in it that you have to weed through to find what you really want to know.)

Comment: I don't understand how to use this

Comment: @johnktejik - Look into how the standard components work in Swing. My answer is written with the assumption that the reader already knows how to display a GUI with a textbox or something in Swing, and just expands on how to go from displaying a standard component to making your own component and displaying that instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
}
```

[image]

Comment: How does this even work?  Running this code or creating a new instance of this class does nothing for me.  :(