# How to make a Rect in Java?

Tags: java, rect

I have been scanning the internet for half an hour and the Rects people suggest do not work so I wanted to know what you guys would suggest.

Comment: Are you trying to draw a rectangle?

Comment: Start with the question "What *is* a rect"? Then you'll know what *data* to model. then ask yourself "What do I need to do with a rect?", that'll tell you what methods to write.

Comment: JavaFX or which framework are you using?

Comment: @Sebastian I. Yes

Comment: @danny Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964768/simple-java-2d-graphics-draw-a-rectangle Please take a look at @Hovercraft full of Eels answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple code in here which is made by a 2D grid

```
 import java.awt.Graphics;

 import javax.swing.JComponent;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

 public void paint(Graphics g) {
 g.drawRect (10, 10, 200, 200);  
 }
  }

  public class DrawRect {
 public static void main(String[] a) {
   JFrame window = new JFrame();


window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
  window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
   window.setVisible(true);
   }
  }
```

Output :

[image]

Otherwise use the `drawRect()` method of a Graphics object. This method looks like:

```
drawRect(int  x, int  y, 
    int  width, int  height)
```

It draws the outline of a rectangle using the current pen color. The left and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width respectively. The top and bottom edges of the rectangle are at y and y + height respectively.

This method is also used to draw a square. This applet draws a rectangle around the entire drawing area, then puts another rectangle in the center.